# Black screen when changing scene Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, screen, phaser-framework

I'm having a problem changing scenes when I reach the area that should trigger the second level in the game I'm developing. For some reasons instead of showing the second level the game shows a black screen and no errors on the console. I think that the answer to my question is here (http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/37617-trouble-changing-scenes-in-phaser-3/)  as the guy who asked the question had my problem and managed to resolve it, but I don't understand his last post.

the way I call the second scene in my first scene is the function:

```
PassaggioLivello() {
  if(this.player.sprite.x > 15400){
      this.scene.start(MainScene2);
  }   
}
```

And both scenes are included in the config file:

```
import {MainScene} from "./main-scene.js";
import {MainScene2} from "./main-scene.js";

let config = {
   type: Phaser.AUTO,
   width: 1280,
   height: 720,
   backgroundColor: "#000c1f",
   parent: "game-container",
   scene: [MainScene, MainScene2],
   pixelArt: true,
   physics: { default: "matter" },
   plugins: {
      scene: [
      {
      plugin: PhaserMatterCollisionPlugin, // The plugin class
      key: "matterCollision", // Where to store in Scene.Systems, e.g. 
     scene.sys.matterCollision
    mapping: "matterCollision" // Where to store in the Scene, e.g. scene.matterCollision
  }
]
}
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Can you please help me? I don't understand my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this.scene.start()` method requires the identifying key of the scene you want to start--not the scene object itself.

Each scene being imported should have a key declared in the constructor method, like this:

```
constructor() {
    super({ key: 'game' });
}
```

Then, you should be able to start the scene you want by calling `this.scene.start('game');`